# Mi aplicación se detiene con el error "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Al ejecutar mi aplicación mediante el simulador, se detiene automáticamente sin terminar de ejecutarse. Entre todos los errores pone que se debe a esto :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Adjunto el código java de ambas pantalla:

Main:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText texto;
private Button boton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Tener acceso y referencia a los controles del programa

    texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.texto);
    boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton);

    //comienza la funcion onClick

    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        // creamos el intent
        Intent intent=
                new Intent(MainActivity.this, SaludoActivity.class);

        //La comunicacione entre actividades

        Bundle b =new Bundle();
        //añadimos un dato de tipo String mediante el método putString(clave, valor)
        b.putString("NOMBRE", texto.getText().toString());

        //añadimos el intent

        intent.putExtras(b);

        //iniciamos actividad

        startActivity(intent);

    }
    } );
}
}
```

Segunda pantalla:

```
package soto.javi.prueba1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SaludoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView mostrar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saludo);

    mostrar= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mostrar);

    //Recuperamos la información pasada en el intent

    Bundle bundle= this.getIntent().getExtras();

    //construimos el mensaje que se va a mostrar

    mostrar.setText("Hola" + bundle.getString("NOMBRE"));


}
}
```

Y los xml de ambos:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="soto.javi.prueba1.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/descripcion"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:id="@+id/texto" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/nombre"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/texto"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/boton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/boton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_saludo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_saludo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="soto.javi.prueba1.SaludoActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="194dp"
        android:id="@+id/mostrar"
        tools:textSize="24sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Jsoto he agreado una respuesta, para mi el error es simplemente lo que indica el mensaje, estas realizando casting incorrecto a los elementos. El problema real basado en tu error en realidad es un casting incorrecto, no un id que no existe:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realmente le estás intentando asignar a tu `EditText` un id que no existe. En tu caso, le tendrías que asignar el id `nombre`:

```
texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombre);
```

Como veo que ha habido malentendidos, cuando pongo **un id que no existe** me refiero a **un id que no existe para ese EditText**.

Para dejar totalmente completa mi respuesta voy a hacer referencia al porque da ese error. En realidad, es porque has utilizado un id de un `TextView` al intentar a hacer la referencia a tu `EditText`, con lo cual te salta el error como que no puede hacer dicha referencia.

Esto se puede deducir del error (he recalcado lo importante):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompat**TextView** **cannot be cast to** android.widget.**EditText**

Cuando habla de casteo (cast) se refiere a que un valor que está definido con un tipo se puede usar como otro. Sin embargo, tenemos que estar seguros de que el valor que casteamos sea compatible con el tipo de elemento al que queremos castear. En caso contrario, el cast será erróneo y nos dará un error muy similar al anterior (dependiendo de los tipos de datos que estemos intentando castear).

Es decir, cuando usas `findViewById(R.id.texto);` realmente lo que estás haciendo es buscar una vista con ese ID. Recupera esa vista (la cual es un `TextView`) y la intenta convertir a `EditText`, por lo tanto, la vista que recuperamos no corresponde con el cast que le queremos asignar.

Comment: Soy nuevo en el desarrollo de aplicaciones. Tenia entendido que cuando utilizaba: `texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombre) `  debia poner el id que  habia asignado a mi EditText, ¿no?

Comment: @J.Soto Así es, de hecho, el id para tu `EditText` se lo defines en esta línea: `android:id="@+id/nombre"`. Por lo tanto su id es `nombre`.

Comment: tienes toda la razón, se me habian ido los ojos a esta línea `android:layout_below="@+id/texto"`, muchas gracias

Comment: @J.Soto En caso de que quisieras que tuviera un id diferente simplemente cambia el valor `nombre` por tu valor deseado.

Comment: No lo creo. Según la consola el error es por que tu `View` es de tipo `AppCompatTextView`, pero cuando casteas lo haces usando otro tipo de `View` `EditText`

Comment: @marlonpya El error lo explica bien el amigo Elenasys. Yo he sido más directo y le he puesto como solucionarlo, no el porqué del error (igual ha sido fallo mío por no ponerlo). Sin embargo, poniendo el id correctamente ese error desaparecerá, ya que lo estarás casteando bien con el id que realmente tiene el EditText.

Comment: @marlonpya Si te fijas, ya tiene un id asignado para ese EditText. Sin embargo, está usando un id de otro elemento diferente. Cambiando eso el código funcionará perfectamente.

Comment: @marlonpya Para evitar todas las dudas, he hecho una última edición refiriendome al error.

Answer (score 4):

**El problema real basado en tu error en realidad es un casting incorrecto**, no un id que no existe:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.EditText

Que se genera al no poder realizar la conversión de un tipo `TextView` a `EditText`.

Es causado porque tratas de realizar un cast de tipo `EditText` a un `Widget` con `id` `texto`:

```java
texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.texto);
```

Y este elemento en realidad es un `TextView`:

```xml
<TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/descripcion"
       android:textSize="24sp"
       android:id="@+id/texto" />
```

---

Por ejemplo el layout `activity_main.xml` que cargas mediante:

```java
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

contienes 3 elementos que son :

```xml
<TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/descripcion"
       android:textSize="24sp"
       android:id="@+id/texto" />

   <EditText
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="text"
       android:text=""
       android:ems="10"
       android:id="@+id/nombre"
       android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
       android:textSize="24sp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/texto"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

   <Button
       android:text="@string/boton"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/boton"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Para obtener las referencias debes realizar el `casting` correcto de acuerdo a su tipo:

```java
private TextView texto;
private EditText nombre;
private Button boton;

...
...
...

texto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto);
nombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nombre);
boton = (Boton)findViewById(R.id.boton);
```

Comment: Creo que ha habido un poco de malentendido. Sin embargo, ya he puesto un comentario para aclararlo. En realidad lo que le quería explicar al OP es que no había un id para ese EditText. En cambio tu le explicas el porque del error, yo he sido más directo. Gracias por completar lo que yo no he dicho! Buena respuesta ^^

Comment: @J.Soto y Error404, No hay mal entendido, es que en realidad los elementos con esos id existen, el problema es : AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Comment: El error indica el problema verdadero, Hey me acaban de dar otro voto "fantasma" el cual comento en este post. http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/604/obtengo-puntos-negativos-pero-no-me-muestra-en-el-listado-de-logros-que-alguien  hahaha  (づ◔ ͜ʖ◔)づ

Comment: Sí, a mí tampoco se me han marcado todos los puntos negativos. Y sí, por eso de que tenía los dos ids creados me limité simplemente a darle la solución al problema. Igual mi fallo estuvo en no poner la causa del error ya que he obtenido muchos negativos. ¿Debería volver a editarla @Elenasys indicando todo el proceso? Aunque realmente lo veía innecesario para algo tan básico como cambiar un id.

Comment: @Error404 hey yo veo tu respuesta como una solución también. (づ◔ ͜ʖ◔)づ

Comment: @Error404  y Elenasys no se quien os ha votado en negativo, pero a mi me habéis sido de gran ayuda si os sirve de algo. Estoy intentando iniciarme por mi cuenta en la programación en android y voy un poco perdido, pero cada vez que pregunto algo aquí sois de gran ayuda. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @J.Soto No sabes lo gratificante que es oir eso :)